# Electron AutoUpdater not working from the private gitlab repo

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am new to electron and gitlab both I have created a test project to check the autoupdate functionality it is working with the public github repo but I have a project requirement to make it work with the gitlab private repo.

This is my app-update.yml

```
provider: generic
url: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/main/raw/dist?job=build
updaterCacheDirName: auto-update-electron-updater
```

I have also tried this url

```
provider: generic
url: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags
updaterCacheDirName: auto-update-electron-updater
```

I have provided the acess token.

```
autoUpdater.requestHeaders = { "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "My_TOKEN_Value" };
```

my package.json file

```
 "build": {
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags"
      }
    ],
    "asar": false,
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true
    }
  },
```

And used this URL too

```
"build": {
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/main/raw/dist?job=build"
      }
    ],
    "asar": false,
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true
    }
  },
```

I was unable to setup my ci/cd for gitlab to make realeases. So I manually created release 2.0.1 in gitlab.

This is the error msg I am getting:
Error: Cannot find channel "latest.yml" update info: HttpError: 404
"method: GET url: [https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags/latest.yml?noCache=1hf3mvvlc\n\nPlease](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/%7BMY_PROJECT_ID%7D/repository/tags/latest.yml?noCache=1hf3mvvlc%5Cn%5CnPlease) double check that your authentication token is correct. Due to security reasons, actual status maybe not reported, but 404.\n"
Headers: {

I am creating my build with electron-builder
How do i know my token is coorect and why my app is not updating?

Comment: There could be many reasons gitlab uses the artifact.zip to update your file.
Now first of all setup your ci/cd.
```
 autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
                provider: 'generic',
                channel: 'latest',
                url: 'http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{projectid}/jobs/artifacts/{branch_name}/raw/dist?job={job_name}',
            });
```